# color and legend in bar3 matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, stack, legend

I am using something like the following commands to stack four set of data and plot them using bar3 in matlab.  How can I set different color and legend  for each stack of data ?

Figure attached below.

```
figure(100);

for i=1:4
     bar3(data.matrix{i})
     hold on;
end
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 0):

*About colorizing each bar, the solution would be:*

```
Y=[ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 3 4 5];
h = bar3(Y);
cm = get(gcf,'colormap');  % Use the current colormap.
cnt = 0;
for jj = 1:length(h)
    xd = get(h(jj),'xdata');
    yd = get(h(jj),'ydata');
    zd = get(h(jj),'zdata');
    delete(h(jj))    
    idx = [0;find(all(isnan(xd),2))];
    if jj == 1
        S = zeros(length(h)*(length(idx)-1),1);
        dv = floor(size(cm,1)/length(S));
    end
    for ii = 1:length(idx)-1
        cnt = cnt + 1;
        S(cnt) = surface(xd(idx(ii)+1:idx(ii+1)-1,:),...
                         yd(idx(ii)+1:idx(ii+1)-1,:),...
                         zd(idx(ii)+1:idx(ii+1)-1,:),...
                         'facecolor',cm((cnt-1)*dv+1,:));
    end
end
rotate3d
```

[source and additional information here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5424-how-to-colorize-individual-bar-in-bar3)

*Note*: Matlab help on bar3 plots is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)